# How to retrieve the value for the Key in the Web.Config using DictionarySectionHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web-config

How to fetch the corresponding value of a key that I would get dynamically. I wish to use the system defined **DictionarySectionHandler** to do the job, of fetching the data from my custom built config section in the **Web.config** file

Code block in Web.Config

```
<section name="domainsource" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler"/>

  <domainSource>
         <add key="0" value="170" />
         <add key="1" value="171" />
         <add key="2" value="172" />
         <add key="3" value="173" />
         <add key="12" value="174" />
  </domainSource>
```

Sourcecode in the main cs file from where I wish to retrieve the data from the Web.Config

```
Hashtable statusCodes = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("domainSource") as Hashtable;
vDomainSource = statusCodes[vDomainID];
```

This is where I am stuck vDomainID would be a value 0/1/2/3/12, based on this value I need to fetch its respective Source from the Web.Config. Any help on this aspect would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a missspelling in the defintion of the section domainsource -> domainSource. Further ensure that the  elemnt is defined in an  element. Then it should work.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  <section name="domainSource" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler"/>
    </configSections>
  <domainSource>
    <add key="0" value="170" />
    <add key="1" value="171" />
    <add key="2" value="172" />
    <add key="3" value="173" />
    <add key="12" value="174" />
  </domainSource>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yup, thats a good catch. Thanks have corrected the misspelled section name, but there seems to an issue with the following part of code it doesn't seem to work. `code`Hashtable statusCodes = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("domainSource") as Hashtable;
vDomainSource = statusCodes[vDomainID];`code`
It errors out with the following error message "object reference not set to an instance"

Comment: Have tested it in an empty application, works as expected. Check if statusCodes is null. If not there must be an error elsewhere in your logic.

Comment: Awesome this worked out for me too :) Thanks a ton.. I really appreciate your help on this.